# Close all modal from a factory in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have a view that has a controller called Controller A, which generates a popup. When this popup is generated,  runs a factory that creates a new popup, above the first popup. I do not know how to close this last popup with some function in the same factory. I want to close all the popups that are open, with some function inside this factory.

//the first modal is created, it is controller A.

```
var modalInstances = [];
var modalScope = $scope.$new();
  modalInstances.push($modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'restablecer_contrasena.html',
      scope: modalScope
  }));

  popup.fn_generatePopup();
```

//factory that create a new modal

```
.factory('popup', function($modal,$state) {
 var oPopup= {};
 var modalInstances = [];
 oPopup.fn_generatePopup = function() {
  modalInstances.push($modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'templates/popup/popup_generico.html',
      controller: 'popupController',
  }));
}
return oPopup;
})
```

In the second modal I will have a button, that when I click on it, I want to close all the popups that are open.But I do not know how to close them.

Comment: in your factory create a method dismissAll that will go through the modalInstances and call a $modal.close

Comment: @sexta13 Excuse my ignorance, but what should I put in the factory? $modal.dismissAll();?   With this all open modals are closed?

Comment: @yavg inside the factory callback function, you should create a new function and append it to the `oPopup` object, this function (which @sexta13 suggested to call `dismissAll` ) should iterate through the `modalInstances` array (a `for` loop should be useful here) and call the $modal.close method on each instance of the modal